# Generalization of the action for unbounded systems?

Tags: reference-request, dynamical-systems

In dynamical systems, specifically in Physics, the action is usually defined as the integral
$$
J = \oint p_i dq_i,
$$
where the repeated indexes indicate a sum over the relevant degrees of freedom of the given problem. I'm just wondering if it exists a generalization of this action to something like an "action" but for unconstrained systems. For instance, if one has an harmonic oscillator of infinite period, the system is still integrable and it might seem plausible to want to define a kind of equivalent $\tilde{J}$. Another example, in fact closely connected to the previous example, I think, is the free particle.

Comment: Why is that integral over a closed loop? Suppose you meant the [Abbreviated action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_(physics)#Abbreviated_action_(functional)) $J=\int_{t_0}^{t_1}p_i(t)\,\dot q_i(t)\,dt$ why is that system constrained? OK: The abbreviated action is used in connection with the Maupertuis principle which differs from the Hamilton principle in the sense that the variation is taken only over paths with constant energy. That is a constraint. In the Hamilton principle we use an action that incorporates potential energy and there is no such constraint.

Comment: In the Hamilton principle, energy conservation comes from the Noether theorem when the Lagrangian does not depend explicitly on time.